# Is there any way in php to make SWITCH opreator compare cases strict?

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I have such control structure:

```
switch ($var) {
   case TRUE: 
   break;

   case FALSE:
   break;

   case NULL:
   break;
}
```

And my `NULL` case is never invoked because as I found in php manual:

> Note that switch/case does **loose comparision**.

I know I can use `IF` instead of `SWITCH` but I wouldn't like to, I have already some `IF's` in every `CASE` of my `SWITCH`.

Is there any way to rewrite somehow `SWITCH` or to use some tricks to make it compare values strict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
switch (true) {
   case $var === TRUE: 
   break;

   case $var === FALSE:
   break;

   case $var === NULL:
   break;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you. But does it make php to evaluate every CASE every time?

Comment: @Green It's exactly the same as with each switch statement - the first case that evaluates to true is entered, and the execution stops on the first break statement

Answer (score 0):

That's the way the switch construct work -- there is not much you can do about it.

The only way I see would be to make some modifications to the PHP source-code and recompile it ; but, then, you wouldn't be running "PHP" anymore *(and your code would rely on something else than "PHP")*

Answer (score 0):

*2020 update*

PHP 8 has a strict version of `switch`; **[`match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php)**.

```php
match ($var) {
  true => ...,
  false => ...,
  null => ...,
};
```

There are some slight differences with switch. `match` is an expression (the result is returned) and branches only support single-line expressions.